# How can i change my model value on button click in Razor?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently im working on a project where i have two buttons.
"Windows Login" and "Login". When i click on "Windows Login" i would like to submit the form and before submitting i would like to change my model `choosenProvider` string property value to "Windows".

Here is my model:

```
public class LogInUserViewModel
{

    public LogInUserViewModel() { }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    public string ChoosenProvider { get; set; } = "idsrv";
}
```

And here is my Razor page:

```
<body>
    <div class="background">
        <div class="login-area">
            <br />
            <div class="login-title">Control Unit Registry</div>
            <br />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-warning-login" })
            <div class="holder-form-login">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="text-login">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "input-name-login" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-warning-login" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="text-login">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "input-password-login" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-warning-login" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ChoosenProvider)
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="holder-button-login">
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button-login" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="holder-button-login">
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Windows Login" class="button-login" onclick="chooseWindowsProvider()" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="link-register-login">
                <a href="register">Register</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the only page what i have in razor and it completely drives me mad.
You can see that i was experiencing with:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ChoosenProvider)
```

And javascript `onclick()` but it did not change the value.

So to SUM UP:
I dunno how to change `choosenProvider` property value to "Windows", and then submit the form, on button click.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What code do you have in `chooseWindowsProvider()`?

Comment: i already deleted it but it had something like getdocumentbyid().value = "Windows", if i remeber well it changed the value but after submitting the value was still "idsrv" and not "windows", so my guess was js was executed later than submit :)

Comment: Is all this code located within a `Html.BeginForm()` ?

Comment: Yes, it is located in one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okey i finally found it out, i hope it will help someone in the future, also please not that intelisense will might tell you that x or y function on field dont even exists but they do.

So the solution was that js was executed later then the submit, so the thing you need to do is:

1. Change the button type to `<input type="button"` from `type="submit"`
2. Then insert the following script at the end of your file

```html
<script>
    function chooseWindowsProvider() {
        document.getElementById('ChoosenProvider').value = 'Windows';
        document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

So we are basically submitting the form from js rather then from the button so this way we can assign the string value before the submitting.

Some additional info:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ChoosenProvider)
```

Already contains an id because its HTML result is:

```
<input id="ChoosenProvider" name="ChoosenProvider" type="hidden" value="idsrv" />
```

And finally how you can add an id to your form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm"}))
```